# Changes in app behaviour after Xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have updated my Xcode to version 12.0 and my app started to act weird.
First I noticed that all of the `ZStack` views are acting differently, for example:

The following code used to show a pop-up in the middle of the screen when a button is clicked. After the update, the same code shows the pop-up in the upper-left corner of the screen (It's important to notice that I have not done ANY changes to the code between the `Xcode` updates)

```
ZStack{
 if self.showLoading {
    VStack{
       Spacer()
       waitingToMove()
       Spacer()
    }
 }
}
```

Just for reference, this is the popup code:

```
struct waitingToMove : View {
    @State var isVisable = false
    @State private var shouldAnimate = false
    var body : some View {
        GeometryReader {_ in
            VStack(spacing: 6){
                Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.shield")
.resizable().frame(width: 35, height: 40).foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                Text("Creating account")
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text("Please wait while being transferred!")
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
               HStack {
                   Circle()
                       .fill(Color.blue)
                       .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                       .scaleEffect(self.shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                       .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever())
                   Circle()
                       .fill(Color.blue)
                       .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                       .scaleEffect(self.shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                       .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever().delay(0.3))
                   Circle()
                       .fill(Color.blue)
                       .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                       .scaleEffect(self.shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.5)
                       .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever().delay(0.6))
               }
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/1.15, height: 200)
            .scaleEffect(self.isVisable ? 1 : 0)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
                .onAppear{
                    withAnimation(.spring()){
                        self.isVisable.toggle()
                    }
            }
            
        }.scaleEffect(self.isVisable ? 1 : 0).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:UIScreen.main.bounds.height + 500)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.35).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)).onAppear {
            self.shouldAnimate = true
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, all of my menus are displaying weirdly in all screen sizes, the left image is the original way the menus showed and the right one how the menus are showing now:

[image] [image]

This is the way I display all my menus:

```
ZStack{
if self.editingNote {
                ZStack{
                    Color.black.opacity(self.backOpacity).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    VStack{
                        Menu()
                    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).background(Color.white) .cornerRadius(15)
.offset(y: self.editNoteViewOffset.height)
.onAppear {
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.1)){
                            self.editNoteViewOffset.height = CGFloat(200)
                        }
                    }.gesture(DragGesture()
                        .onChanged({ value in
                            self.editNoteViewOffset.height = value.translation.height + 200
                            
                        }).onEnded({ value in
                            if value.translation.height > UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3 {
                                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.1)){
                                    self.backOpacity = 0.0
                                    self.editNoteViewOffset.height = 850
                                }
                                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
                                    self.backOpacity = 0.4
                                    self.editingNote = false
                                }
                            } else {
                                self.editNoteViewOffset.height = 200
                            }
                        }))
                    
           }
     }
}
```

In addition, all of my .padding() and .listRowInsets() are acting differently since the update.
How can I return to the way my app ran on the `Xcode 11.6` while still staying on `Xcode 12.0`?
Or, what am I doing wrong in any of the code above?

Comment: Isn’t this the well known problem where geometry reader coordinates system has changed?

Comment: I did not know there is such a problem, is there an article about it or something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+14+geometryReader

Comment: So I need to fix everything to work with the new changes because apparently it’s not a bug but rather the previous version was a bug?